# Flexmock a django model object gives model objects?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, flexmock

I am trying to flexmock a django model object, but when I mock it then also it gives me that object itself. How can I mock it then ?

So there was a model object I created in a method like this

```
aa = ModelName()
```

now when I tried to mock it, like this

```
from flexmock import flexmock
bb = flexmock(aa)
```

the type of bb is still django model object, it's not flexmock object. How can I mock it successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully, the flexmock function is actually modifying the `aa` object, so it is a partial mock. It has all the necessary methods.